# Get single values from angularfire 2 observable

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I'm having some problems understanding how to handle a stream of objects that is emitted from an angularfire 2 observable.

Look at this example:

```
// create observable
var observalbe = Rx.Observable.range(1, 3);

// Prints out each item
var subscription = observalbe.subscribe(
  x => console.log(x)
);
```

This will output:

```
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

That's the behavior I'm expecting when subscribing to an observable, as far as I understand it.

Now I want to subscribe to an realtime db collection on firebase with angularfire 2:

```
// af is an instance of AngularFire-Service that is injected in the constructor
var observable = af.database.list('/items');

observable.subscribe(
    x => console.log(x)
);
```

I was expecting, that my arrow function will be called for every single object that exists in this collection, and that it also will be called every time when a new item is added to the firebase collection.

Instead the arrow function is only called one time and given an array with all objects. When a new object is added to the collection, the arrow function is called again and is again passed the whole collection, instead of only the new object.

Am I doing something wrong here? In my case I would very much prefer the arrow function to be called for every item in the collection.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what you're trying to do I guess, but you can map it.

```
observable.subscribe(x => {
  x.map(y => console.log(y));
});
```